# How strong is the Second Ratio Test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

The [Second Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Second_ratio_test) is a relatively new convergence test, which we can give as

> Let $\sum_n a_n$ be a series with positive terms. For $k \in \{0,1\}$ we write
>   $$ L_k = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+k}/a_n , \quad l_k = \liminf_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+k}/a_n $$
>
> - If 
>     $ \max\{ L_0,L_1 \} < 1/2 ,$
>     $\sum_n a_n$ converges.
> - If
>     $ \min\{ l_0,l_1 \} > 1/2 , $
>     $\sum_n a_n$ diverges. Otherwise, the test is inconclusive.

(The second condition can probably be replaced by $a_{2n+k}/a_n \geq 1$ for all sufficiently large $n$ if we want to be as strong as possible.)

We recall that a convergence test A is stronger than one B if A resolves the convergence/divergence of any series that B resolves. (One may wish to separate the convergence test from the divergence test for greater specificity.) For example, we all know that the Root Test is stronger than the Ratio Test. A natural question is thus if the Second Ratio Test has a similar relationship to the Root Test, or other more venerable tests. Currently known:

- The Second Ratio Test resolves the convergence/divergence of the $p$-series $\sum_n n^{-p}$, for $p \neq 1$ anyway. The Root Test does not.
- The Second Ratio Test is stronger than the Ratio Test and Raabe's Test, at least on the convergence side.

These are proved in [this paper](http://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/kyle.pdf) cited in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Also:

- The Second Ratio Test requires $a_n \neq 0$, whereas the Root Test avoids this. But this still raises the question of whether one is stronger than the other in their common domain of validity.
- The Second Ratio Test is not as strong as the Condensation Test where both apply: it does not resolve $n^{-1} (\log n)^{-p}$, whereas the Condensation Test does. But the Condensation Test requires a monotonically decreasing sequence of terms. In this case, there is a [follow-up paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-323275) that discusses more general cases.
- More interestingly, Bertrand's Test (third in the De Morgan Hierarchy) *does* resolve $n^{-1} (\log n)^{-p}$, so the Second Ratio Test is not stronger than Bertrand's Test.

(For the definitions of the other tests mentioned above, the linked Wikipedia article has them.)

So this leaves two questions:

1. If $a_n>0$, is the Second Ratio Test stronger than the Root Test?
2. Is Bertrand's Test stronger than the Second Ratio Test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no -- we can construct counterexamples using series which are constant over long intervals.

Question 1: consider the series $\sum_n a_n$ such that $a_n = 2^{-3^{k+1}}$ for $3^k \leq n < 3^{k+1}$. This is convergent by the root test, since for any $n$, $|a_n| < 1$, hence taking the appropriate value of $k$, we have $|a_n|^{1/n} \leq |a_n|^{1/3^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$. The second ratio test is inconclusive, since $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} = 1$ when $n = 3^k$, meaning $L_0 \geq 1$.

Question 2: consider the series $\sum_n b_n$ such that $b_n = 4^{-k}$ for $2^k \leq n < 2^{k+1}$. This is convergent by the second ratio test, since $L_0 = L_1 = \frac{1}{4}$, but Bertrand's test is inconclusive, as the term
$$\ln n \left(n \left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} - 1\right) - 1\right)$$
becomes arbitrarily large for $n$ of the form $2^k - 1$, while it is negative for all other $n$.

Comment: Interesting. The second one dashes all hope of further comparison with the de Morgan tests. However, I wonder if there is an "expanded" ("evaporated"?) series of this kind that works in the first question for all $m$th ratio tests, since examples of the present sort will have problems with sufficiently large $m$.

Comment: assuming I'm interpreting your question right, try $a_n = 2^{-2^{(k+1)^2}}$ for $2^{k^2} \leq n < 2^{(k+1)^2}$; this is still convergent by the root test but every $m$-th ratio test should be inconclusive

Comment: Yes, that should do. Cool.